# Counting function arguments at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-macros

I'm trying to count the number of arguments to a function at compile time (I'm wrapping sprintf up in some templates for compile time checks and type safety). I need to check that the number of arguments matches the number of formatting placeholders at compile time. A first pass at this is pretty simple:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
constexpr u32
CountArgs(Args&&... args)
{
    return sizeof...(args);
}

constexpr u32
CountFormatSpecifiers(c8* format);

template <typename... Args>
c8*
String_FormatImpl(c8* format, Args&&... args);

#define String_Format(format, ...) \
    String_FormatImpl(format, __VA_ARGS__); \
    static_assert(CountFormatSpecifiers(format) == CountArgs(__VA_ARGS__));
```

But this breaks down for certain types of arguments. Namely, when passing a reference.

```cpp
int x = 0;
int& xRef = x;
String_Format("%", xRef);
```

The compiler complains about `CountArgs(__VA_ARGS__)` because `xRef` is not a constant expression. I don't need the value, just the ability to count it. I could wrap it in `sizeof` or something similar, but that's tough when all I have is `__VA_ARGS__` to work with.

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Diwffy

Comment: Please at least post the compiler error. A minimal reproducible example is always welcomed.

Comment: Added a godbolt link

Comment: You could place the `static_assert` inside the function that you pass the pack to. Even if the parameters are not `constexpr` the size of the pack is.

Comment: `CountFormatSpecifiers(format)` is not constexpr inside the function.

Comment: In that case, how are you gonna check it's value at compile time? If it's not `constexpr` it can never be used in a `static_assert`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. That's not a problem though. Just pass in the return value of `CountFormatSpecifiers(format)` as a template parameter to the same function and use that value to compare against `sizeof...(Args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your macro to something like this

```
#define String_Format(format, ...) \
    String_FormatImpl<CountFormatSpecifiers(format)>(format, __VA_ARGS__);

template <std::size_t I, typename... Args>
void String_FormatImpl(const char* format, Args&&...) {
    static_assert(I == sizeof...(Args));
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's ends up really nasty, but it's workable. The issue is that the template parameters to `String_FormatImpl` are inferred. So that means I'd need to make a wrapper template like `template <u32 N> struct Size {};` to pass the size as an 'argument' and let it get inferred as well.

Comment: You can explicitly specify the first parameter and let the rest be inferred.

Comment: Holy moly I didn't know that. I think this will work.

Comment: It is not clear to me why the original code does not work. Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58472449/261217

Comment: @Mikhail From what I can tell the only reason is that the standard currently says so, so the compiler is allowed to do this and still be conformant.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `decltype()` and `std::integral_constant` ?

I mean... you can declare (only declare: no needs of define it) the following function (EDIT: modified, following a Davis Herring's suggestion (thanks!), to accept const references; this permits to works also with non copyable types)

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)> CArgs (Args const & ...);
```

and use it, by example

```
#define bar(num, ...) \
    static_assert(num == decltype(CArgs(__VA_ARGS__))::value);
```

This way you don't use the `__VA_ARGS__` values in a `static_assert()` but the type returned by a function that accept `__VA_ARGS__`.

And the type returned (`std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>`) contain the number (accessible through `::value`), as compile-time constant, of the arguments.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Args>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)> CArgs (Args const & ...);

#define bar(num, ...) \
    static_assert(num == decltype(CArgs(__VA_ARGS__))::value);

int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   int& xRef = x;

   //..VV  number of the following arguments    
   bar(3u, x, xRef, 42);
}
```

Comment: @DavisHerring - Good point. I didn't thinked to non-copyable types. Thanks.