# Why does a constexpr function behave differently for a reference?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Inspired by [Counting function arguments at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468574/counting-function-arguments-at-compile-time?noredirect=1#comment103271603_58468574)

Consider [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/shhyZN):

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr int count(Args&&...)
{
    return sizeof...(Args);
}

void foo(int value)
{
    static_assert(count(value) >= 0);  // OK

    const int& ref = 7;
    static_assert(count(ref) >= 0);  // Error
}
```

First `static_assert` works fine. Second gives an error:

```
<source>:12:19: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(count(ref) >= 0);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:25: note: initializer of 'ref' is not a constant expression
    static_assert(count(ref) >= 0);
                        ^
<source>:11:16: note: declared here
    const int& ref = 7;
               ^
```

Both situations are surprising to me. Why does the first `static_assert` work fine, while `value` is clearly not known at compile time? Why does the second `static_assert` not work, while the only fundamental difference with the first is that it is supplied with a reference, not a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is usual with constant expressions, we need to consult the list in **[expr.const]** and see if any sub-expression we wrote is disallowed. In this case the pertinent bullet is this one:

> [2.11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11) an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>   either
>
> - it is initialized with a constant expression or
> - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

That's what knocks `ref` out of the water. It did not come into existence with the evaluation of `count(ref)` since it's declared beforehand, and it's not initialized with a constant expression. That may be a `7`, but the actual initializer is a temporary object, since that's what the reference binds with.

As for `value` being usable. That is because there is no bullet that disallows `value` itself. And the reference argument now has its lifetime begin with the evaluation of `count(value)`, and not beforehand. So it's a valid reference to create in a constant expression, but it just can't be used to read `value`.

Comment: Damn, I love this wording "An expression e is a core constant expression unless ..." and you have 22 items. Is there any logic behind it?.. Because two situations that I mentioned just do not make sense to me :(

Comment: @Mikhail - It (constant expressions) started with very short white list. Then in C++11 with the introduction of `constexpr` it became a blacklist. Every published standard since sees the list grow smaller, so we get *more* constant expressions. As for this rule in particular, I suppose it's just an unfortunate circumstance with the wording. There is nothing inherently better in `value` than in the temporary the reference is bound too. Maybe the rule will be tuned and relaxed a bit in the future, who knows.